# Example Inheritance Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, inheritance, model

Im planning to make a website using Cakephp, and one of the 'requerimients' is using inheritance in the database.

The parent Entity pretends to have common properties but most important an id (key attribute)
that is passed to its subentities, which of course have their own set of attributes.

Does Cakephp support this feature? If it does, can anybody provide an easy example of using inheritance? (not multiple inheritance btw)

I'll appreciate your answers.

Comment: Wow! Thanks guys. I can see that there are too many ways to solve this issue. 
But all of them,  seem to be overwhelming, at least for a cakephp noob guy like me . Could you post a sample code or a tutorial link  please?

Comment: I wonder that if you dig into yourself deeply in Cakephp do you still need that OOP style inheritance or the ORM HasOne,HasMany features are efficient what you described in your topic.

Answer (score 0):

while I don't think it supports it directly you can do that with some Set class magic. one of the most awesome classes around.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1487/Set

and

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1508/merge

if it is quite simple stuff you are doing, array_merge() will do it for you too

You would easily be able to create a behavior that does this in the afterFind() callback so that its transparently done in one place and all ready for your view just doing a normal $this->Model->find('all') etc

Comment: I dont quite get this, particulary if you are facing with CRUDs. Can you ilustrate this with an easy sample code?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement this behavior via CakePHP's built-in relational mapping (hasOne):

http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together

You can then modify the AppModel class and implement an afterFind method (to work with all models) and massage/merge the data.

Comment: So you are trying to solve this with Composition , is it correct? With a HAS-A relation instead of IS-A?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using Doctrine as an ORM, which supports inheritance through column aggregation:
http://dqminh.com/integrate-doctrine-orm-with-cakephp-part-1

Comment: he specified cakephp: if you can get Doctrine to work with Cake's relationship system I will give your vote back.

Comment: The link provided simply loads doctrine via composition into an appModel - it has no relationship support, no validation support and no find syntax sugar like the usual cake orm. If he manages to support more than simply pulling doctrine in as a vendor and telling the model to not use the cake datasources then maybe this would be a viable solution. Looks like he is either not planning to implement this further or it is a long way off.

Answer (score 0):

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/taylor.luk/2008/10/22/inheritable-behavior-missing-link-of-cake-model

This is a behavior written some time ago - it might be old but it should give you a very good foundation for understanding how to manage STI (single table inheritance) using Cake.

** EDITS **

From the article I linked - which might not be current or working code. I mentioned it as a starting point for you to work out your own behavior code.

The type is inferred by the class type - and the structure you are talking about only applies to the single table inheritance type of setup. Make absolutely sure you are doing the import of the parent class like the examples show. IE:

```
<?php
    ...
    App::import('Model', 'Person');
    class Manager extends Person
    { 
        ...
    }
?>
```

Comment: I tried this using an easy example but still doesnt work. They say that you have to use a var char attribute 'type' on the parent table. That way, Cakephp would 'automatically' detect which subclass are you referring to. Do you have to manually configured like a foreign key? :S

Comment: Like I said - the code probably doesn't work. It is very old - but it is the idea that you need. You can look through it and figure out what it should be doing and fix it for your version of cake.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to CakePHP (as in one week's worth of experience) but have run into the same issue. As has been hinted at already here, it seems that composition is the most conventional way of getting toward Model extension (as you mentioned in a comment using Has-A instead of Is-A).

Here's what I'm trying and hoping works for my relatively simple set of use cases:

```
//'Super Class'
class Log extends AppModel {
     var $name = 'Log';    
}

//'Sub Class'
class SharedLog extends AppModel { 
    var $name = 'SharedLog';
    var $hasOne = 'Log';
    var $validate = array(
        'log_id' => array(
            'logRule-1' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',  
            ),
            'logRule-2' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',  
            )  
        )
    );
}
```

I'm hoping this get's close to what one would need a subclass to do. When you explicitly ask for SharedLogs you'll have access to the Log attributes. If you make the request from the perspective of a Log you won't have access to any SharedLog extended attributes (but that makes sense because if you're going through a collection of Logs you wouldn't know which are the super class and which are the sub class).

I think the validate variable is enough to prevent orphans and duplicates in the database.

Speaking of the database, I went out on a limb made it so that the shared_logs table doesn't have an id column and instead uses log_id as its primary key. I'd love to get some feedback on this setup because I'm completely new to the framework and don't have that sixth sense for when code "just feels wrong" in this context.

EDIT: I was just thinking that assuming I'm not completely going about this the wrong way (and I'd like to think I'm not) this solution offers a pretty straight forward way to make an instance of the super class into an instance of the subclass. Since a Log may not be shared until after it is created. This might just make the belabored point that I should have been thinking composition from the beginning.